# WPF data to bind style

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, styles

here is my style .xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="TabItem" x:Key="gMetroTabItem">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,2,6,2" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="5" />

    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TabItemHeaderData}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="rootText" Text="{Binding tabText}" FontSize="26.67"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

</Style>
```

here is my TabItemHeaderData:

```
public class TabItemHeaderData
{
    public String tabText { get; set; }
    public object Content { get; set; }
    public object tabIconOff { get; set; }
    public object tabIconOn { get; set; }
}
```

my question is: the code of the style seems right, I bind the property tabText to the Text, but how can I send the TabItemHeaderData from my window code? actually is like this:

```
<TabItem Style="{StaticResource gMetroTabItem}">
  <Grid>
  ...
  </Grid>
</TabItem>
```

Comment: If you want to know how you can parse your changes you made on UI to your `TabItemHeaderData`, do it via Binding: `Text="{Binding tabText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`

Comment: thanks, but after I need to add some other data (if you look TabItemHeaderData have more properties..)